# How to recover deleted data from AWS PostgreSQL database for Django project?

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services

I tried to add a new field in my existing Django project. I run the following command to do it:

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate appname zero
manage.py makemigration
manage.py migrate
```

Now I have lost all my previous data from the database (PostgreSQL) for that application.  The migration folder only has the most recent migration file. How can I retrieve previous data? I am using AWS PostgreSQL in the project. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You can reverse the migrate to resume the previous schema, but not the lost data. If you are using AWS RDS, try to check if there is any auto backup or snapshot generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS RDS,

Check for snapshots of RDS.
Then, you can create a new RDS from that snapshot which must be having the schema at the time when snapshot was generated.

Comment: I was panicked and could not think properly. AWS has the snapshots of RDS. Problem solved after restoring the previous snapshot. Thanks all.